# How do I get the print to reprint the input but with the abs, chr, len functions?

Tags: python, variables, printing

I got everything except for the getValue function working. I'm prompted to input a positive integer, negative integer, an integer between 48-122, and a string. Once I type them all in, I would like it to reprint them all but with the abs, chr, and len functions where shown. This is where I get a syntax error.

```
def main():
    posInteger()
    negInteger()
    myChar()
    myString()
    getValues()

def posInteger():
    #Declaring positive integer value
    posInt = (input('Enter a positive integer: ')


def negInteger():
    #Declaring negative integer value
    negInt = input('Enter a negative integer:')

def myChar():
    #Declaring integer
    myCh = input('Enter an integer between 48 and 122 incluseive: ')

def myString():
    #Declaring string 
    myStr = input('Enter a string: ')

def getValues():
        #Prints the variables back out to user
    print ('The positive int is,', abs(posInt))
    print('textbody', abs(negInt))
    print('textbody', chr(myCh))
    print('textbody', len(myStr))
#raiser posInt by power 4

main()
```

edit:

This is how my program looks when it runs (w/ error)

```
Enter a positive integer: 45
Enter a negative integer:-1
Enter an integer between 48 and 122 incluseive: 90
Enter a string: daf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\.Drexel Affil\info\info108\W3\scrap.py", line 38, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\.Drexel Affil\info\info108\W3\scrap.py", line 7, in main
    getValues()
  File "D:\.Drexel Affil\info\info108\W3\scrap.py", line 32, in getValues
    print('The positive int is,', abs(posInt))
TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'str'
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Please [edit] your question and add the **full text** of the error. Also, you're missing a closing `)` in the line `posInt = (input('Enter a positive integer: ')`. You don't need the initial `(`, so just get rid of it.

Comment: @MattDMo The error is obvious if you read the code.

Comment: @orlp I've read the code, and have my thoughts as to what the error is, but I want to OP to read the error carefully, think about it, and possibly discover what's causing it. "Teach a man to fish..." and all that.

Comment: @MattDMo In a novice programmer there is no concept of variable scope, and thinking about it won't suddenly sprout the idea. It needs to be explicitly taught and mentioned, and trying to have the OP discover it themselves doesn't add educational value, just frustration.

Comment: @orlp it depends on what the actual error is. I agree that concepts like scope need to be learned. However, OP just edited the post and said it was a syntax error (still didn't add the text of it, though), so something else is going on as well...

Comment: Again, please [edit] your post and show us the ***full text*** of the error. Just saying it's a syntax error is not helpful at all.

Comment: @MattDMo I edited my answer to resolve the syntax error.

Comment: @orlp I just saw, looks good.

Comment: @MattDMo Thanks for helping me with the syntax error. I didn't realize I had an extra parenthesis. I've edited the post to add the error as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here, the problem lies not in your using functions, but in your variable management.

For example, the variable `posInt` that you read in `posInteger` is a variable that is local to this function. Hence, you cannot get its value in `getValues`, as it has been forgotten as soon as `posInt` returned.

So you can go one of at least two ways.

First way, easiest : stop using functions, and just put all the code in the `main` function. Works, but is not a good way to think.

Second way, better : return the `posInt` & co. variables at the end of the respective functions, and give them as arguments to the (ill-named ?) `getValues` function. You can get more details for how to do it on a tutorial dealing with functions, such as [this one](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Variables in functions in Python are [local](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) to the function by default. So this doesn't work:

```
def f():
    a = 1

f()
print(a)
```

In order to make `a` available outside of the function, you have to use `global`:

```
def f():
    global a
    a = 1
```

---

P.S.: your syntax error is on this line (you have an extraneous opening parenthesis):

```
osInt = (input('Enter a positive integer: ')
```

Comment: Good answer, but any reason as to why not edit the deleted post and undelete it?

Comment: Teaching to use `global` to someone learning to write functions might be a bad idea, I think...

Comment: @BhargavRao Because my previous answer was simply incorrect, so I deleted my incorrect answer and posted a correct one instead. It's an entirely different answer, so I didn't feel like an edit was appropriate.

Comment: @Ekleog I agree, but this question is about the OP not understanding variable scoping. I don't have time to explain all best practices for every novice every time - they can read a good book for that.

Comment: I added the global like you suggested and still have an error. Just trying to figure out how to show it...

Comment: @Ryan Hint: the return type of `input()` is a string. `abs(x)` wants x to be a number.

Comment: @orlp So I'd have to use `int(x)` instead of `input(x)` right? But then that doesn't seem to work when I change them.

Comment: @Ryan First you have to get the input, then turn it into an integer. So `int(input("your message"))`.

Comment: @orlp Thanks for your help, I appreciate it. I'm still messing around with the code though and where you suggested that I make each variable global, could I just declare the variables in the main function instead?

Comment: @Ryan What I'd really suggest is to use `return` and function arguments to pass around the data you found.

Comment: @orlp I just spent 10 minutes looking at the past powerpoints to see if  I could have a better response for you, but I honestly am pretty unfamiliar with `return`.

Answer (score 0):

If this is Python 2...Raw_input worked for the string, also you dont even need all those functions listing the commands as such will work.

```
posInt = (input('Enter a positive integer: '))
negInt = input('Enter a negative integer:')
myCh = input('Enter an integer between 48 and 122 incluseive: ')
myStr = raw_input('Enter a string: ')
print ('The positive int is,', abs(posInt))
print('textbody', abs(negInt))
print('textbody', chr(myCh))
print('textbody', len(myStr))
#raiser posInt by power 4
```